# How to increase the counter by 1 every time the image is a multiple of 3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I try to make that every time *imact* is a multiple of 3, *cont* is incremented by 1.

The expression below already does it, but it doesn't work for me because it breaks the functionality of my program, when I specify *cont = 0* dynamically, that is, if it was passed cont = 0, then it increments cont in 1, it not in loop to 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2, the same thing if passed it cont = 1, it increments it by 2 afterwards because the condition is met. That using the expression I put below.

Because I try to do:

```
img1 = 0 cont 0
img2 = 1 cont 0
img3 = 2 cont 0
img4 = 3 cont 1
img5 = 4 cont 1
img6 = 5 cont 1
img7 = 6 cont 2
img8 = 7 cont 2
img9 = 8 cont 2
```

etc.

I mean *img1* in position 0 should be *cont* = 0, *img2* in position 1 should be *cont* = 0, *img3* in position 2 should be *cont* = 0, *img4* in position 3 should be *cont* = 1 etc.

the variables *img1* *img2* *img3* *img4* are image 1,2,3,4 which is the current image to be compared.

There is a way to simplify this expression, or another way to do it.

```
if((imact != 0)&&(imact %3)==0){
cont++;
}
```

The *imact* variable is the current image being compared if it is a multiple of 3

The variable *cont* is the counter that keeps track of the increment.

Comment: Seems you simply want `cont = Math.floor(imact / 3)`

Comment: You could always just calculate it when needed:  `cont = Math.floor(imact/3)` (ha, trincot beat me to it by 7 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to increment the variable cont by 1 every time the variable `imact` is a multiple of 3, but you also want to ensure that the initial value of `cont` is preserved.

You can achieve this by modifying your code slightly. Instead of using the if statement to check if `imact` is a multiple of 3, you can use the modulo operator (%) to calculate the remainder when `imact` is divided by 3. If the remainder is 0, then imact is a multiple of 3, and you can increment cont.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

python

```
if imact % 3 == 0:
    cont = cont + imact // 3  # Increment cont by the quotient of imact divided by 3
```

In this code, `imact` // 3 calculates the integer division of `imact` by 3, which gives you the number of times `imact` is divisible by 3. You can add this quotient to `cont` to achieve the desired behavior.

Lastly, keep in mind that 0 % 3 = 0 or the remained of 0 when divided by 3 is 0 or false. If you are further unsure as to how to approach the issue, you can always just create a separate if for the 0th case.

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP there's no form of iteration (or real JavaScript) so it's difficult to guess as to what is really needed. But by just going by what's posted you could use `parseInt()`. `parseInt()` will convert a given number or string into an integer. If `x = 3.33` then `parseInt(x)` would be `3`. So in this specific case:

```
let x = parseInt(cont/imact);
```

```js
const counter = (cont, imact) => parseInt(cont/imact);

console.log(counter(7, 3));
console.log(counter(0, 3));
```